# Determine if a parametric equation's trajectory lies on a circle?

Tags: calculus, parametric

I have a question as follows:

Determine whether the following trajectory lies on a circle.  If so, find the radius of the circle and show that the position vector and velocity vector are everywhere orthogonal.

$r(t)=\langle2\sin(t)+\sqrt{21}\cos(t),\ \ \sqrt{21}\sin(t)-2\cos(t)\rangle$ for $0 \le t \le2\pi$

I'm not really sure where to start with this one.  I found the velocity vector to be

$r'(t)=\langle2\cos(t)-\sqrt{21}\sin(t),\ \ \sqrt{21}\cos(t)+2\sin(t)\rangle$

but I'm not sure how to determine if it's on a circle, or the rest of the question...

Comment: A curve lies on a circle if its position vector is always the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does because $x^2(t) + y^2(t) = 25 = 5^2 \Rightarrow r = 5, C = (0,0)$

Comment: How did you know to plug in 25?  I'm missing some key step here.  I understand the polar and rectangular representations of coordinates, but what's the substitution you made here?

Comment: $2^2 + \sqrt{21}^2 = 25$